# Apache redirect

Tags: apache, redirect

I would like to redirect a URL using RedirectMatch within Apache eg,

/test/one/?? redirect to /test/two/??

where the ?? represents any string that follows

The redirect i'm using below does a straight redirect but doesnt match any string after...
RedirectMatch Permanent ^/test/one?$ /test/two/

Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/test/one/(.+)$ /test/two/$1
```

if that does not work, change ^/test/one into ^test/one

make sure mod_rewrite is enabled

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite for this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/test/one/(.*) /test/two/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The `R` flag redirects the page rather than internally rewriting the URI. `301` is the HTTP status code for "Permanently Moved" - if you'd rather use another, you can change it to [one of these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).