# Apache redirect fool .aspx

Tags: linux, apache

I have an apache server running in Linux and I'm wondering how I would go about redirecting urls? I want to do this via apache not by adding a header or redirect into the individual files. The goal is to get around having to deal with .aspx

Example1:

```
VISITING: wwww.myserver.com/file1.aspx
Will take you to: www/myserver.com/file2.php
```

Example2:

```
VISITING: www.myserver.com/file1.aspx?command1=set&command2=set
Will take you to: www.myserver.com/file2.php?command1=set&command2=set
```

Comment: I'm working through the following example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295148/apache-redirect

Comment: ok but that link is using a `.htaccess` and enabling the `mod_rewrite`. Why are you using apache, on linux and have `.aspx` files?

Comment: I don't want to use .aspx. I want to redirect a request away from a .aspx page to a php page while keeping all the $_GET data

Comment: Have you already enabled the mod_rewrite Apache module?

Comment: Yes, and I believe I've gotten it working following the example outlined in
: stackoverflow.com/questions/1295148/apache-redirect 
just needed to used RewriteRule ^file1.aspx file2.php [L,R=301]

Comment: if it is solved please post a answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Without using mod_rewrite, you can simply use mod_alias, in your vhost/server config or in an htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /file1.aspx /file2.php
```

Comment: Excellent way to do it! I have converted some of my websites from ASP.NET to PHP. This has saved me a LOT of time! Thank you!