# Route a specific path to a specific EC2 instance using Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but if so I'm looking for the best way to do it.

Say I want to host my blog for example.com on it's own EC2 instance, and I want the path to my blog to be example.com/blog

Is it possible to route all requests to example.com/blog/* to one instance, and all other requests to that domain elsewhere?

My web server is Apache.

Thanks!

Comment: Route 53 is just a DNS server. It just maps a domain name to and IP. So you can't do this with Route 53.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now do this with Application Load Balancer and path-based routing: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-application-load-balancer-cli.html#path-based-routing-aws-cli

Answer (score 2):

Certainly it's possible, but not with DNS nor with an ELB. The most common solution to this is to use a web server that issues a 301 or 302 redirect.

In your case, example.com would point to whatever the main site is. The web server (nginx or Apache httpd, perhaps) hosting example.com would have a redirect for example.com/blog/* that is found at another destination.

Here's an SO post on using [Nginx for a redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294481/how-to-redirect-a-url-in-nginx) and for using [Apache for a redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295148/apache-redirect).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you would have to proxy your requests through an instance handling example.com. How you configure this depends on your web server.

Some examples on how to configure this:

- nginx: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule
- Apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Apache2 Server, so you can achieve this very easily by creating a Virtual Host.

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/vchost1.com.conf
```

Create Virtual Configuration using the above command, it copies the complete code of content from the default file provided by the apache2 Server.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/vchost1.com.conf
```

start configuring host & domain according to your requirements

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

here also, you can multiple Virtual Host configurations in a single file, start configuring and enjoy hacking.

you can also multiple web applications in a single instance by using the same method and theis reference.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart